# SQLITE3, copy data to a new DB file with a different TABLE Schema

Tags: database, sqlite

I have 2 different SQLITE3 DB files with following `RESULT TABLES`:

> DB1.db:

```
  result ("ID","Name")
```

> DB2.db

```
  result ("ID","City","Town","Name")
```

How can I copy data from DB1.result table into DB2.result table with fixed values `City=city1, Town=town1`

Any solution with SQL commands, or a script solution with any language is more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a result in the desired form, you can use fixed values with SELECT:

```
SELECT ID, 'city1', 'town1', Name FROM result;
```

To copy between two databases, you can [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) one to the other:

```
ATTACH 'DB2.db' AS db2;
```

... and then copy between the tables:

```
INSERT INTO db2.result(ID, City, Town, Name)
SELECT ID, 'city1', 'town1', Name
FROM main.result;
```